# Change to a "parallel" directory in a single instruction

Tags: windows, command-line, path, navigation

I would like to move directly from the "Classwork" directory into the "Assembly" directory with a single command line instruction. If possible, I would like to use relative paths to do this:

[image: Transversal Command Prompt]

I would venture to guess that there is a simple command to accomplish this, but I am not familiar with the terminology. It's possible that I don't know how to phrase this question correctly, hence my inability to find a pre-existing answer.

Apologies if I am duplicating a question and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
cd ..\Assembly
```

`..` means move up one so it would put you in the parent Documents directory and then get you into Assembly

Comment: Thank you very much! This may be silly as well, but let's say there is a folder called "x86" inside of "Assembly". Would I simply append that so the command would read `cd ..\Assembly\x86`?

Comment: @Shrout1 try it :)

Comment: @Shrout1: Tab completion is of great help in all such cases. Just type a letter or two and press Tab, or just press Tab to cycle between all available choices.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Works great! Seems like an inane question, yet somehow I have never played with it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Karan Thank you! I will keep that in mind in the future. Greatly appreciate the help.